# How to divide the count of 2 different values within the same 1 column in Tableau?

Tags: filter, tableau-api, calculation, divide, calculated-field

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am trying to divide the data above, that is in the same column within my raw data. The one column name is "Status". I split it under this column into 2 separate columns within Tableau.

How would I create a calculation to divide T & D by each other? For an example, I would like to divide 166/1523, 155/1535, etc.

How do I differentiate between these 2 under the same column "Status".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SUM (IF [Status] = "T" THEN [Your Measure] END)
/
SUM (IF [Status] = "D" THEN [Your Measure] END)
```

Comment: I tried this calculation & it is not giving me the division outcome.
It duplicates my same number of records

Comment: Now, it is just giving me a 1 or a 0, no actual division outcome for each row

Comment: You may have to try it on a different sheet. The Status field is trying to put the calculated field in its dimension. Let me know if that works.

Comment: The 1 or 0 could need to be formatted to percentage with decimal points. It may be rounding to 1 or 0.

Comment: I tried to format it & it still stays as 0 or 1 & yes, this is a different sheet as well.

Comment: Is Status removed from the Columns?

Comment: Oh yes! I moved it & now it is working. Thank you so much!

Comment: It there a way to filter out Status D from the view & still have the calculations output? Everytime I only select T in the filter for my view, the calculation disappears :(

Comment: A LOD calculated field could possibly do that. You would wrap the current calculated field in this function. { FIXED [row_dimension] : the calculated field above }

Comment: Would the LOD be FIXED?

Comment: That's right. And you may have to aggregate the calculated field again by putting it in a SUM() to avoid an error.

Comment: It is saying my calculation is valid but it is still giving me 0:

{ FIXED [Subs Set]:SUM(IF [Status] = "T" then [Number of Records] END)/ 
SUM(IF [Status] = "D" then [Number of Records] END)}

Does this look correct to you?

Comment: That does look correct. Tableau can be finicky with these situations. I often have to add more comma separated dimensions before the colon of the FIXED calculation.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: It would be something like: { FIXED  [dimension 1],[dimension 2]  : calculation}

Comment: Oh yes, that worked! You are so amazing. I truly do appreciate your help with this. Thank you again :)

Comment: Glad to help! No problem!